# Android - redirect a fragment in main activity from notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-push-notification

I have a loginActivity and MainActivity with multiple fragments and one of them is called NotificationFragment.

Requirement: Assuming user is already logged in and is currently on Home Fragment (inside Main Activity) and app is in background. Now they receive a push notification, user should be redirected to Notification Fragment (on Main Activity).

As of now, Login Activity is receiving intent data from notification. Login Activity is our launch activity currently.

Question: How should Login Activity (on back stack) inform Main Activity to redirect user from Home Fragment to Notification Fragment?

Manifest looks like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.X.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Sets the intent action to view the activity -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <!-- Allows the link to be opened from a web browser -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Allows the deep link to be used without specifying the app name -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.X.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: If user logged in then y ur intent data received by login activity? If it received by Mainactivity you can move to fragment using `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: LoginActivity is our launch activity.

Comment: If user loggedin then no need to launch login activity again? Have u used splash screen?

Comment: I understand, but as I said LoginActivity is our default launcher activity and is receiving Push notifications. Edited my question to include manifest. We don't have SplashActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 private void sendMyNotification(String title,String message) {

    //On click of notification it redirect to this Activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_appicon);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"Default")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti_new)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

it will trigger the main activity.

Add

> android:launchMode="singleTask" in your mainactivity to avoid running mutiple instance of MainActivity.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Comment: Welcome glad to help..! Happy coding.!